# Large retain count with a recent created object. Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, release, retaincount

I'm getting an strange case of excessive retain counts for a view controller that I'm loading when a button is pushed.

This is the code:

```
-(IBAction)new
{
    if (!viewSpace)
        viewSpace = [[ViewSpace alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewSpace" bundle:nil];

    viewSpace.delegate = self;

    viewSpace.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, viewSpace.view.frame.size.width, viewSpace.view.frame.size.height);

    [self presentModalViewController:viewSpace animated:YES];

    NSLog(@"Count Retain: %d",[viewSpace retainCount]);

}
-(void)viewSpaceWasDissmissed:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [viewSpace release];    
    NSLog(@"Count Retain: %d",[viewSpace retainCount]);
}
```

When the IBAction New is executed first time, the retain count is 5 when just is created. (It must be 1).

When the ViewSpace object must be unload calls viewSpaceWasDismissed function in order to remove the modal view and release the previous object.

The problem is that never the retain count reach 0 and the dealloc method of ViewSpace never is called causing memory leaks.

My question is how is possible that a recently created ViewController have 5 retains? I made sure that is never created before.

Thanks.

Comment: `retainCount` is entirely useless.  You are wasting your time thinking about it.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is the dealloc of ViewSpace object never is reached. This causes a high memory usage in my app and crashes.

Comment: @bbum are you watching the rss feed for the retainCount tag, or what? ;)

Comment: @user1132003 Then you need to figure out where the extra retains are coming from, which `retainCount` won't tell you.  Use the Allocations instrument and turn on retain event tracking.  Then look at all the retain events and figure out which one isn't balanced by a `release`.

Comment: @abizem Yeah -- it provides a bit of entertainment.  I fully admit to being easily amused.

Answer (score 4):

Cocoa is probably retaining the view controller 4 times internally for reasons of its own. This isn't a problem.

More generally, the -retainCount method is useless for reasons like this, and you should never call it. It will not help you, and it will confuse you.

To debug your leak, I suggest using the leaks Instrument, inspecting the object, and analyzing where each retain and release is coming from to determine whether any are incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Check the documentation for `-retainCount`. I believe it says that you should not be calling it yourself - you just need to take care of any retains that you cause, and don't worry about the 'actual' retain count.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing two things wrong here:

1. **The Current view controller retains the modally presented view controller** and releaseds it when it is dismissed. So you should release `viewSpace` after it is presented, and you don't need the release message in the `dismissModalViewController` method. As an aside `ViewSpace` is a poor name for a view controller. I had to read to the line where you are presenting it as a view controller before I knew it was a view controller. I think `ViewSpaceController` is a more descriptive name.
2. **You are using `retainCount`** which is always a bad idea. All that matters is that in your `new` method you created an owned object (with the `alloc`) and you balanced that ownership with a release (or at least you will do when you put in the correction I suggested in point 1) That's it. You took ownership of an object and you released it. The `retainCount` method tells you absolutely nothing that can be of any use to you. Don't do it. Just balance ownerships with release, and that is all that matters.

Comment: I applied as suggested. But the problem stills remaining. dealloc method never is reached and I'm having problems of memory usage.

Comment: `retainCount` isn't going to help you find the leak. Run your app through instruments and see what' really happening with your view controller.

Comment: I did, I removed the retain count, and I'm using instruments. The problem is that each time the ViewSpace object is loaded and unloaded the memory increases 1,30 Mb. After several open/close actions the app crashes.

Comment: If the dealloc method is used to make the clean up of an object, and dealloc is automatically called when retain count reaches zero, why I have to call release in the same method where is created and not in a different method? This object must be alive until the user closes the object ViewSpace?

Comment: You need to release it because it is retained by the current view controller when it is presented, and the current view controller also released it when it is dismissed. Which is why you need to balance your alloc with an init in the same function as I explained in point 1).

Comment: Ok, then, as I understand, the problem is that the parent of ViewSpace never is dismissed because is the main menu window. Which is the best practice to release all the memory used by ViewSpace during the execution? Thanks for each response :)

Answer (score -3):

I'm not 100% sure of every count but here are some:

- Instantiation - 1
- NIB - 1+
- Strong Properties (1+)

Additionally any properties that list it as a strong property (in ARC).
I noticed that when you launch a nib and you use components of the controller in the nib design, it will increase reference counts (in a strong manner) on the controller instance.

Comment: ARC doesn't apply to this code. The calls to `release` and `retainCount` are not allowed under ARC.